# Does knockout have if else?

Tags: knockout-3.0

Can I do if / else in knockout? 
I see there are a few answered questions regarding this from a while ago, but after doing some research I'm having a hard time figuring out if this is currently included in knockout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Knockout does not have "else" binding. Instead you can do the following:

```
    <div data-bind="if: capital">
        Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: !capital()">
        <b>No capital</b>
    </div>
```

The documentation about "if" binding you can read here: [if-binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html)

Comment: https://github.com/mbest/knockout-switch-case - I was just wondering is this means i can currently use it